# Is it possible for an asynchronous function call to finish between two synchronous statements?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I'm working on a script that would fetch a specified resource `r` from the server on demand using an AJAX call (asynchronously, of course, as it is by default), then call a callback function `f` with the resource returned by the server.

To increase efficiency, I'd like the script not to initiate another AJAX call if the given resource is already being requested, but instead perform the callback when the already loading resource has finished downloading:

**JavaScript**

```
var nowLoading = {};

/**
 * @param {String} r - The resource identifier
 * @param {Object} f - Callback function with returned resource
 */
function Load(r, f)
{
    if (nowLoading.hasOwnProperty(r))
    {
        // the given resource is already being requested, listen to it being finished
        nowLoading[r].OnReady = function () {
            // ...
            f(resource);
        };
    }
    else
    {
        // make a new request
        var xhr = XHRFactory.Spawn();
        nowLoading[r] = xhr;

        xhr.OnReady = function () {
            // ...
            f(resource);
        };

        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
    }
};
```

**Is there even a *marginal* possibility that the AJAX call finishes between** `nowLoading.hasOwnProperty(r)` **and** `nowLoading[r].OnReady = fn` **statements?**

Or did I misunderstand JS in this regard, and `OnReady` can only happen after the sequential statements have finished executing?

The former would mean that it is possible for the callback attached to a property of `nowLoading` to never get executed, since `OnReady` occurred before attaching anything to it.

---

NOTE: `OnReady` is a special, custom case of `XHR.onreadystatechange`. Also note, that for simplicity's sake, `OnReady` does not clear the previous handler, but adds a new one.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with the concept to offer you a definitive answer on this special case, but it may be possible to put a synchronous series in a webworker while asynchronous execution continues on the main tread or another worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript uses a single thread for execution (There are some engines which attempy to multi thread, but they take care of making things look like they happened on a single thread.)

Now, for your question. Since you are running some piece of code, and there are no dual threads (When the call is done, it will register the callback to be run on the main thread).

So, no, there is NO chance the code can run between the statements, because it runs on the same thread, and will only run once the current execution stack is fully unwound.

Here´s the top Google result for Javascript event loop, which should give an overview of what´s happening in the background to make all this work together.

http://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html

As for the second part of your question:

> The former would mean that it is possible for the callback attached to
>   a property of nowLoading to never get executed, since OnReady occurred
>   before attaching anything to it.

Javascript's model does indeed mean this could happen if the call finishes synchronously. In this case however, since you are using Ajax, the call will never be executed synchronously, and as such the callback will always be registered.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. That's a feature of JS:

> [**"Run-to-completion"**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#.22Run-to-completion.22)
>
> Each message is processed completely before any other message is
>   processed. This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your
>   program, including the fact that **whenever a function runs**, it cannot
>   be pre-empted and **will run entirely before any other code runs** (and
>   can modify data the function manipulates). This differs from C, for
>   instance, where if a function runs in a thread, it can be stopped at
>   any point to run some other code in another thread.

Therefore, once you start running some synchronous code, asynchronous code will wait until the synchronous one has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous functions are exactly that: Asyncronous. However, since JS is single-threaded (unless you are using [HTML5's Web Workers](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=0A6Hilo8UW8) which are truly multi-threaded, but it isn't the case here), it means that event callbacks functions will not execute until the runtime engine is free.

So, the answer is NO. Callbacks in your code cannot be executed between 2 synchronous statements.